# Linux Installation: Modifying default ISO for additional packages and root ssh key

Tags: debian, virtualization, installation

I am interested in learning a good way of modifying a Linux distribution's installation ISO such that:

1. The root user has a *default* ssh key (**authorized_keys**)
2. Password Logins are disabled (**sshd_config**)
3. Additional packages are installed.

I am not sure of the best way to accomplish this.  I have read up a little on using debian's **preseeding** functionality, but it seems that preseeding is limited to automatically answering the questions asked during an installation.

I will be modifying this ISO (most likely to be debian flavour) for use in installing new virtualized machines via KVM.

Answer (score 6):

The usual way to do this is:

- generate a `preseed` or `kickstart` config file to match you needs with regards to basic items like partitioning, network configuration, locale and/or keymap
- use the `%post` section in the case of a `kickstart` installation or `d-i preseed/late-command in-target` in the case of a `preseed` installation to run custom commands to finish the installation.

However, I'd recommend using this resource to ensure connectivity and to grant access to you configuration management system, and delegate on it the handling of the rest of the configurable items.

Comment: I agree, it's the job of kickstart/preseed to partition the drive, then get enough of a system installed so you can run your configuration manager of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I´m using [simple-cdd](http://packages.debian.org/stable/simple-cdd) for this task. It can create an iso with every package you wish to install. Through a simple bash-script (called $PROFILE.postinst) you can copy/generate your configs or ssh-keys.

**Hint:** with `isohybrid $output.iso` you can alter your image so it boots from usb after dd`ing it to a stick.